# Excel VBA: Use .Find to identify cell contents and copy row to a new tab (multiple search terms)

Tags: vba, excel, find, copy-paste

Please could you help a noob out?

If any of my search words ("transfer", "indicate" or "water") are within a cell in Column B on Sheet 1 (i.e. not an exact match, the cell may be = "national water" or "water-monthly" or "transfer to 1" or "TJ.indicate" and the cell should still be found) I would like to copy the whole row to Sheet 2. 
The data I am searching runs across 4 columns, and the search term would only be contained in Column B. I am using Excel 2016 or 2013 depending which computer I am working on.

I am wildly inexperienced and desperately need your help. I have cobbled together the following code,  but I am aware that the .find terms don't correlate with how I am asking it to return the results, and don't run the searches on multiple terms.

Please could you help me fix this code? I would be so very grateful.

```html
Option Explicit

Sub SearchForString()

   Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   'Start search in row 4
   LSearchRow = 4

   'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet3 (row counter variable)
   LCopyToRow = 2

   While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

      'If value in column C contains "Transfer", copy entire row to Sheet2
      Set cell = Range("C:C").Find("Transfer", After:=Range("C2"), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy

         'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
         Sheets("Sheet2").Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

         'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
         Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

   'Position on cell A3
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Range("A3").Select

   MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."


End Sub
```

Comment: The above is mashed together from something posted on Stackoverflow and excelmacromastery.com. I have already tried the fuzzy lookup add-in and approximate VLOOKUP but they are either too fuzzy or too strict. It definitely needs to include something that works like LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart

Comment: Your narrative states 'within a cell in Column B' and copies to sheet2 while your code looks in column C and copies to sheet3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop a Find/FindNext within an outer loop through an array of search terms. Collect everything found into a union. Copy that union to the new location.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchForString()

    Dim a As Long, arr As Variant, fnd As Range, cpy As Range, addr as string

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    'populate the array for the outer loop
    arr = Array("transfer", "indicate", "water")

    With Worksheets("sheet1")

        'outer loop through the array
        For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            'locate first instance
            Set fnd = .Columns("B").Find(what:=arr(a), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
               'record address of first find
                addr = fnd.Address
                'seed the cpy range object
                If cpy Is Nothing Then Set cpy = fnd.EntireRow
                Do
                    'build union
                    Set cpy = Union(cpy, fnd.EntireRow)

                    'look for another
                    Set fnd = .Columns("B").FindNext(after:=fnd)

                'keep finding new matches until it loops back to the first
                Loop Until fnd.Address = addr
            End If
        Next a

    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        'one stop copy & paste operation
        cpy.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    Debug.Print Now & " " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this looks fantastic. I am struggling to Run it. VBA is highlighting Sub SearchForString() in yellow and selecting "addr" and indicating that the variable has not been defined. Is this something I have done incorrectly on my side?

Comment: My bad. The *addr* was an afterthought and i forgot to go back and declare it as a string var.

Comment: Thank you so much - it is working perfectly. I really appreciate the help - thank you.